# What are the advantages of using JSON.NET?

Tags: json, .net-4.0

What does this library bring to the table that System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ( or the DataContractJsonSerliaizer ) doesn't do or do well? We're going to be started a project requiring extensive use of JSON and I'm looking at options for handling the serialization / deserialization of objects and collections.